# npm install grpc failed

Tags: node.js, npm, grpc

```
enviroment: node version v8.9.3 npm >5.x
```

start install grpc by npm, I got some errors
`npm install -g grpc`

the errors:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
(/Users/yuham/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/node-
gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.2.0
...
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/yuham/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 
...
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
(/Users/yuham/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/
grpc/node_modules/node-
pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:209:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/yuham/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/node" 
"/Users/yuham/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/
grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--
library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd 
/Users/yuham/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.38
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/Users/yuham/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/bin/node 
/Users/yuham/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-
gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --
module=/Users/yuham/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/
grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-darwin-x64/grpc_node.node --
module_name=grpc_node --
module_path=/Users/yuham/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/
grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-darwin-x64' (1)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.6.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --
library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.6.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I tried to install different version of grpc, but got the same result
while this error caused by node-pre-gyp or node-gyp? My computer system is osx --lts. I can't find any good idea or solution. How to fix it?

Comment: Maybe try updating node-gyp. This package can be a pain sometimes.

Comment: @Frederik.L i updated node-gyp node-pre-gyp to lts vesion, but same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command, it will work

```
npm install -g xxx --unsafe-perm
```

But I don't understand what '--unsafe-perm' means?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the problem was that the package `request` was missing. 
Installing it before installing grpc fixed my issues. 
If you have a package depending on `grpc`, install `request` first.

`yarn add request`

`yarn add grpc`

A colleague mentioned something about the company proxy. Dunno if that's actually the problem, but adding `request`  did fix the issue.